# spring data mongodb create repository implementation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have got problem with repository bean definition. First of all I do not like the new style using to define repository as interface only and do not write own implementation.

So i am write simple interface :

```
public interface UserRepo {

  Member findByUsername(String username);

  Member findByEmail(Email email);

  Institution save(Institution institution);

  User save(User user);
}
```

As you can see that interface do not extending any spring data interfaces, next i am creating my own implementation for that interface:

```
public class UserRepoImpl extends AbstractMongoQuerydslRepo<Member> implements UserRepo {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRepoImpl.class);

  private static final QMember memberQuery = QMember.member;
  private final PathBuilder<Member> memberPath;

  @Autowired
  public UserRepoImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
    super(mongoOperations);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(mongoOperations);
    memberPath = new PathBuilderFactory().create(Member.class);
  }

  …
}
```

So that class have got repository implementation postfix as **Impl**, this is default 
postfix in `EnableMongoRepository` annotation. Next, I add my configuration:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses={UserRepo.class})
public class MongoTestContext extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{
  …
}
```

And I have got error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.xxxxx.infrastructure.repo.UserRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Whats is wrong with my configuration? I also tried to add @Repository annotation in UserRepository and UserRepositoryImpl but its not working. Also my UserRepo and UserRepoImpl have got the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having false expectations to some degree. The `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotations exists to activate exactly the automatic repository mechanism you don't seem to like (and I definitely would like to hear about the reasons for doing so). So with opting out of that mechanism, you also opt out from all the configuration requirements and settings (e.g. the default `Impl` suffix).

So if you really want to implement all of that stuff yourself (which would effectively render you to be the first developer I've met who insists on writing code she actually doesn't have to) you simply need to declare your implementation class as Spring bean - either through annotating it with `@Component/@Repository` and letting the constructor wear an `@Autowired` annotation, or by manually declaring a bean definition through wither XML or JavaConfig.

Comment: But for example if you create app with DDD specyfication, you woult to have got only some method in your repo, maybe not all crud metod. So for that reason i would like write my own implementation. Maybe i need only read and update not all.